# What's the difference in using toString() compared to JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript

In both the cases I get in output the content of the object:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

or

```
alert(obj.toString());
```

so... what's the difference? what are the advantages or disadvantages of each one?

Are there practical examples to show the difference?

Comment: [jsperf test](https://jsperf.com/js-array-to-string/1) for a simple Array

Answer (score 68):

Unless you have a custom object with custom `.toString` method returning `JSON.stringify` of that object, there is no `obj` that would give `obj.toString() == JSON.stringify(obj)`.

When `obj` is an array like `[1,2,3]` then `.toString()` gives:

```
"1,2,3"
```

And `JSON.stringify`:

```
"[1,2,3]"
```

These are close but not quite the same, the JSON serialized one has no ambiguity with commas and directly runs as Javascript or can be parsed as JSON.

See:

```
["1,",2,3].toString();
//"1,,2,3" ... so you can't just split by comma and get original array
//it is in fact impossible to restore the original array from this result

JSON.stringify(["1,",2,3])
//'["1,",2,3]'
//original array can be restored exactly
```

Answer (score 42):

for an object say

```
obj = { a: 'a', '1': 1 }
```

`obj.toString()` gives

```
"[object Object]"
```

`JSON.stringify(obj)` gives

```
"{"1":1,"a":"a"}"
```

For [.toString()](http://es5.github.com/#x9.8), a default value is returned when the argument type is an object. [JSON.stringify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836459%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) on the other hand returns JSON text, which can be converted back into a JSON object by using [JSON.parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

As you might have noticed, while you tried (hopefully), calling `.toString()` which **any** object inherits <sup>(*)</sup> from `Object.prototype.toString()`, returns `[object Object]`.

Thats how its defined internally, returning the internal `[Class]` name from an object. Of course, other *objects* can override this method (remember, its just originally defined on the prototype chain) and return pretty much anything.

`JSON.stringify()` on the other hand, is a method of the JSON object, which kind of *serializes* an object structure into a string version. Hence, *Javascript Object Notation*, it will describe an object with all nested structures in pure *ascii string*.

---

<sup>(*) exception: objects created with `Object.create(null);`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replacer and space parameter in JSON.stringify, passing the replacer argument as a function you can modify the object and space parameter helps you to give extra space before every key value pair.

```
const replacer = (key, value) => {
        // Filtering out properties
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            return 1;
        }
        return value;
    },

    foo = {
        country: 'India',
        state: 'Gujarat',
        district: 45,
        cm: 'car',
        am: 7
    },

    result = JSON.stringify(foo, replacer);

console.log(result) // {"country":"India","state":"Gujarat","district":1,"cm":"car","am":1}
```

Space argument -

```
const obj = { a : 1, b:2};

const obj_str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, '     ');// '\t' gives one tab 

console.log(obj_str)
```

For more details you can visit this [link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)