# How to decode data from kinesis.getRecords in Javascript SDK?

Tags: amazon-kinesis, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to get data from Kinesis data stream:

```
function getRecord(shard_iterator) {

    var getRecParams = {
        ShardIterator: shard_iterator
    };

    kinesis.getRecords(getRecParams, function(err, result) {
            // Loop through all the packages
            for (var record in result.Records) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result.Records[record].Data));
                break; // just to see the first one
            }
            //if (result.NextShardIterator) getRecord(result.NextShardIterator);
    });
}
```

The result I see:

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[123,34,73,110,112,117....,125]}
```

Form AWS CLI I know `data` should be base64-encoded, but here is something different. So how can I get info from the `data` array I see?

Pls note it's not NodeJS but Javascript in browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution, would be nice to have it in doc:

```
var decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
function getRecord(shard_iterator) {

    var getRecParams = {
        ShardIterator: shard_iterator
    };

    kinesis.getRecords(getRecParams, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error in getRecords() from the Kinesis stream.");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            try {
                // Loop through all the packages
                for (var record in result.Records) {
                    data = result.Records[record].Data
                    decoded = JSON.parse(decoder.decode(data));
                    console.log(decoded);
                }
            } catch(err) {
                console.log("Error parsing the package.");
                console.log(err);
            }
            if (result.NextShardIterator) getRecord(result.NextShardIterator);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. In my case I just had to change `JSON.stringify(result.Records[record].Data)` to `result.Records[record].Data.toString()`

To understand `obj.toString()` vs `JSON.stringify(obj)`, here is the link: [What's the difference in using toString() compared to JSON.stringify()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834172/whats-the-difference-in-using-tostring-compared-to-json-stringify)