# Difference between what's passed natively to console.log and toString

Tags: javascript

In the following example:

```js
let s = {x: 1, y: 1};
console.log(s, s.toString());
```

Where is the `'[object Object]'` method defined? Why does printing an object evaluate to something different than doing object.toString() ?

Comment: Regarding the 1st question, see item 19: https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various environments' consoles are generally intended for (and hence optimized for) debugging. If you log an object, the console is likely to show you a full, readable, interactive view of the object. The console does *not* convert logged values to strings before displaying them - that wouldn't be useful for debugging.

When an object has `Object.prototype.toString` called on it, it's required to [go through these steps](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.tostring) in the specification, which will result in `[object SOMETHING]` being logged, where SOMETHING may be `Array`, `Function`, etc, or `Object` if none of those special cases match. For a plain object, none of the special cases match, so you get `[object Object]`.

Answer (score -3):

Replace `s.string()` with `JSON.stringify()`...

Refer here... [What's the difference in using toString() compared to JSON.stringify()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834172/whats-the-difference-in-using-tostring-compared-to-json-stringify) for further

Comment: That wasn't the question...

Comment: I have provided the link for further demonstration